# Default credentials, printing and macOS Sierra

Tags: keychain, printing, macos

We use a Windows print server and until now it was possible to store the needed credentials in the KeyChain. By the first print, OS X asks for username and password with the possibility to remember it.

On all the machines we updated to macOS Sierra, the system asks for the credentials for each print:

[image]

The stored password is correct, and I only need to press "OK".

Is there a way to avoid the confirmation dialog (as on all the previous OS versions)?

Comment: This feels like a bug. I get the same problem when network volumes are auto-mounting — the password is in the Keychain and is filled but I have to OK it, just like your printer problem.